# Is there a way to use python to do specific things in an application?

Tags: python, operating-system

Like for example first open Safari

```
os.system("open /Applications/Safari.app")
```

Then go to a user inputs something else and it will be inputed into the search bar and searched.

Also for this example

```
os.system("open /Applications/Messages.app")
```

Then send a message to someone.

And this example if possible:

```
os.system("open /Applications/Dictionary.app")
```

And search for a word?

Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do that you need to use the application on the macbook called automator. This way, you will have permission to access application's source code and edit it, essentially.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how it works. In your example, you're just using python to execute a shell command. Once the program opens, it's not going to just give you information about what is happening unless it is specifically designed to do so or supports some sort of api.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automate web task - look at [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)

> Selenium Python bindings provides a simple API to write functional/acceptance tests using Selenium WebDriver. Through Selenium Python API you can access all functionalities of Selenium WebDriver in an intuitive way.

Selenium Python bindings provide a convenient API to access Selenium WebDrivers like Firefox, Ie, Chrome, Remote etc.

Here is a link to what is [selenium and webdrivers](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/01_introducing_selenium.jsp)

see you can do this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

see [here for a breakdown of the code](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#example-explained)

For your message example you can use [Skype4Py API](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Skype4Py/)

Answer (score 0):

Those are all OS X apps, so I'm going to take a leap and assume you're using a Mac. The Automator app might be more appropriate for this task as it basically helps you easily write AppleScript applications.

Answer (score 0):

For Web Automation:

1. [Selenium Python Bindings](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)
   I have a detailed example [here](https://github.com/kingmak/SeleniumPythonBindingsForChrome/blob/master/example.py) along with some helpful links.
2. [Splinter](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (simpler than selenium)